# How do I store role<->permission in the cache for best result?

Tags: .net, arrays, caching

I have a table in the DB with two columns, **roles** and **permissions** that looks like this:

**role** - **permission**
user - addItem
admin - removeItem
admin - advancedSearch
guest - simpleSearch
user - editItem
manager - editUser
...etc.

I need to store these in the .net's cache so that I can check if a permission exists for a specific role.

*(Here's the psuedo-code)*

```
if ("permission" is in Cache["role"]) // Authorize access
```

But how do I add and store them in the Cache for best result?

In PHP I'd do something like this I guess:

```
array ( "user"  => array ( "addItem", "editItem"),
        "admin"  => array ( "removeItem", "advancedSearch"),
         ....
```

Is there an equivalent or better/faster way in C#?

Thanks!
/Niklas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>`?

For example:

```
var pairs = new[] { 
    new{Role="user",Permission="addItem"},
    new{Role="admin",Permission="removeItem"},
    new{Role="admin",Permission="advancedSearch"},
    new{Role="guest",Permission="simpleSearch"},
    new{Role="user",Permission="addItem"},
    new{Role="manager",Permission="editUser"},
};
Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> cache = pairs.GroupBy(pair => pair.Role)
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => new HashSet<string>(
          grp.Select(g => g.Permission)));
cache["user"].Contains("addItem");
```

---

Or if reading from a data-reader (comment):

```
var cache = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
using (var reader = GetReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()){
        string role = reader.GetString(0),
            permission = reader.GetString(1);
        HashSet<string> permissions;
        if (!cache.TryGetValue(role, out permissions)){
            cache.Add(role, permissions = new HashSet<string>());
        }
        permissions.Add(permission);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a good an answer as Marks's. I need to add these iteratively while reading from an SqlDataReader. What is the correct syntax for doing this?

Comment: Whether you are a script, a robot or an actual human being... you're saving lives =)

Comment: Wait, how do I check if the cache contains "addItem"? This returns false: cache["user"].Contains("addItem");
While this returns true: cache["user"].Contains("user");

Comment: @niklas - `cache[role].Contains(permission)` should do it

Answer (score 0):

Building on Marcs answer, you can use collection initializers directly inline:

```
var cache = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>()
    {
        { "user", new HashSet<string>() { "addItem" } },
        { "admin", new HashSet<string>() { "removeItem", "advancedSearch" } },
        { "guest", new HashSet<string>() { "simpleSearch" } }
    };
```

Looks a little bit cleaner than the LINQ version, and should be relatively familiar to you with a background in PHP since the syntax is quite similar.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could mark two answers. So to add a role->permission to "cache" in your case how would the correct syntax look like? I need to add these iteratively while reading from an SQLdatareader.

Comment: @Niklas, my version is specifically only for known compile time values which isn't very useful for your use case. I'd suggest looking at something like Linq to Sql rather than using a DataReader if possible. It will make your life a hell of a lot easier.